# Django-gears Assets Path Issue

Tags: python, django, gears

I've been using Django with django-gears in my development environment, and was having good fun with it. I'm now preparing for deployment and set to use **uWSGI** (rather than **manage.py runserver**). Doing so broke something, and the resolution of assets path is now broken. The **GEARS_DIRS** config variable seems to not take effect. I am a relatively new user of Gears, and spent now a good few hours trying to debug this problem.

My settings are:
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**))

```
GEARS_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
u'./assets' is not an absolute path.
```

when rendering, in a template, the following:

```
{% load gears %}
{% load url from future %}
{% load i18n %}
{% css_asset_tag "stylesheets/application.css" %}
{% js_asset_tag "javascripts/application.js" %}
```

with the **css_asset_tag** line highlighted. I tried another option:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

GEARS_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "assets"),
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static"),
)
```

And that resulted in

```
u'./<app_name>/assets' is not an absolute path.
```

Through debugging, I can see that the paths in SITE_ROOT and BASE_DIR are as intended and point to the the directory where the assets and static directories reside.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you deploy according to the official documentation?
http://django-gears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying.html#deploying

Comment: I've missed the deployment step altogether, thinking that deployment means to production and not merely using an WSGI engine. I'll give that a go and report.